# conditionally convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is quick question about the conditionally convergent  but I got confused how to dot it. power series of $(x-2)$ is conditionally convergent at $x=-1$ and it is divergent at $x=6.$ If this statement true or false.   I know it is conditionally convergent means when we apply ratio the limit will be equal or does not exists but does not help to get the answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your power series. When you applied the ratio test on the power series, you will find the interval of convergence, or sometime you find that it only converges at a single point. If you found that the interval of convergence is finite, says, -1 < x < 1. Then what you need to do do is test the end point of the interval. Conditional convergent just means that you may have an alternating series when you plugged in the end-point, and it converge conditionally (with the alternating condition) but it doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: @user209663 how can know my statement is true or false

Comment: The power series of $(x-2)$ converges everywhere, seeing as it's finite. Are you missing something in your question?

Comment: See Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula in Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example: Suppose we have the power series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)2^n} (x-1)^n $$

We want to find the Interval of Convergence. You can either do the Ratio Test or n-th Root test. Let me do the Ratio test here:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigg| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \dfrac{(x-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)2^{n+1} } \cdot \dfrac{(2n-1) 2^n}{(x-1)^n} \bigg| = \dfrac{|x-1|}{2}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1} = \dfrac{|x-1|}{2}$$

We know that we perform the ratio test, if $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| = L <1 $ then the series converges.

Hence, if

$$ \dfrac{|x-1|}{2}< 1$$

then the series converges. This imply that within the interval $-1 < x < 3$ the power series will converge. However, at the point $x=-1$ or at $x= 3$, we don't know exactly what happen because at those points, the ratio test give us $L=1$. When $L=1$ the ratio test is inconclusive. Thus, we must check those points separately!

At $x = -1$ we have: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)2^n} (-1-1)^n  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)2^n} (-2)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)} $$
Which diverges by Harmonic series. Thus the endpoint $x=-1$ can't be included!

At $x = 3$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)2^n} (3-1)^n  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)2^n} (2)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)} $$
Now this series is an ALTERNATING SERIES. The term $b_n = \dfrac{1}{2n-1} $ is decreasing and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$ therefore we can conclude that this series CONVERGES (Conditionally ). This series converges conditionally because the moment you remove the condition $(-1)^n$ the series will diverge!

Thus The INTERVAL of CONVERGENCE is $-1 < x \leq 3$ or $x \in (-1, 3]$. Any  value of $x$ you picked in this interval will give you a CONVERGENT SERIES. Also, within this interval you can do term by term differentiation and integration....

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Typically a series will be conditionally convergent at a point if the point is on the circle of convergence, which looks like a circle centered at $x=2$ and radius $=3$.  The point $x=6$ lies outside the circle, so it diverges there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my question. since the $R=3$ so the series divergent when $|x-2|>3$ and $|6-2|=4>3$ so the statement is correct then.